# Micro Services Transactions in nodejs

Tags: node.js, microservices

I am trying to develop **Micro services** in **Node JS** with **Loop back ORM** and i am using **Apache Kafka** as a message broker. And how do i achieve transactions between those different micro services. And how to handle those Transactions using NodeJS. If any one having the experience kindly provide the solution for it.

Thanks in Advance..